# Computing youngest person among 3 while keeping ages private

Tags: reference-request, multiparty-computation

I already found a protocol to find out who is richer (older) between two parties, but Is there any protocol to find the youngest person among 3 parties, without revealing actual ages?

Comment: i am not sure which one you have, but intuitively, can think of a reduction with $money \equiv \frac{1}{age}$?

Comment: @Subhayan : $\:$ That ignores the main issue, which is going from 2 to 3 parties. $\hspace{1.67 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer i missed that the two party :P Anyway, still can we do like Richer(A,B), Richer(B,C), Richer(C,A) .. age is transitive, so that should work right?

Comment: That would reveal too much information. $\;$

Comment: What security properties do you need? Specifically: active or passive security? Fairness?

Comment: Also, if there's a tie for the youngest, should it give them all or break the tie at random? $\hspace{1.15 in}$

Comment: can i give the following physical protocol (just for fun) .. assume everyone is honest, they all are given a (infinitely/very) long "stick", and they are cut the stick to a length to match their age (eg. a 5 yr old kid will end up with 5 unit(cm,maybe?) length of the stick).. now, they play the following interactive game.. at every round, they show 1 cm of the stick.. so at the $n^{th}$ round, the youngest person would simply declare his entire stick is revealed, and thus we have our youngling :) not efficient, but fun, right?

Comment: that reveals the age of the youngest. The question as to "who is the youngest", and due to the reference to the millionaire problem, it should probably be kept secret who is the youngest. As an answer: Yes, [secure multiparty computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation) can achieve this, the generalization to more than two parties is not that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

There might be better ways to do this, but I wanted to do it with only primitives found in [VIFF](http://viff.dk) (why? because it is the MPC framework I am most familiar with). There could be specialized protocols which are better.

In VIFF, we have access a primitive >= which returns 0 or 1 (false or true). We can do the comparison you seek using that plus some simple arithmetic on secret shared values. I think these are all passive protocols and do not guarantee fairness (if fairness even makes sense in the passive world).

Let the three parties be alice, bob and charlie. They have each secret shared their ages with the others. We'll let a,b,c be the variables that represent the secret shared ages.

We can compute who is the youngest as follows:

```
ab = (b>=a) # is a younger than b?
ba = 1-ab # is b younger than a?
ac = (c>=a) # is a younger than c?
ca = 1-ac # is c younger than a?
bc = (c>=b) # is b younger than c?
cb = 1-bc # is c younger than b?

a_score = ab + ac
b_score = ba + bc
c_score = ca + cb

# At this point we are guaranteed to have a score of 2, a score of 1, and a score of 0.
# Whoever has the score of 2 is the youngest.
reveal(a_score>=2) # if this is 1, then Alice is youngest
reveal(b_score>=2) # if this is 1, then Bob is youngest
reveal(c_score>=2) # if this is 1, then Charlie is youngest
```

This computation only reveals who is the youngest. It does not reveal ages or the overall order. It requires 6 calls to >=. This will also only return 1 person as youngest. To get all of the youngest, you would replace the 2nd, 4th, and 6th lines with another >= instead of a 1-XX.

Comment: how do you compute ab? do you assume a third party or the Millionaire Solution OP was talking about?

Comment: I'm assuming a secure >= comparison function like what is implemented in VIFF. I don't think taking a simple 2-party millionaire solution will work.

Comment: Regarding fairness&passiveness, one could restrict to adversaries whose only misbehavior is aborting partway through the protocol run. $\;$

Comment: I don't know this MPC framework, but the millionaire's problem is just one example for MPC, and you can proceed in a similar way: Express the algorithm as a circuit, then use methods like garbled circuits and oblivious transfer for the execution.

Comment: @tylo, correct me if I am wrong, but aren't garbled circuits typically only used for 2 party computation? I think there are constructions for more than 2 party computation which use garbled circuits, but they tend to be less efficient than secret sharing based constructions.

Comment: Yes, mikeazo, if the function to be computed is algebraic, secret sharing should offer a higher efficiency. But since there are value comparisons, I'm not sure about that. I just had a look into the documentation of the noted MPC module, and they also seem to use secret sharing based computations only, so you're probably right.